# In Swift debugger, how can I see where an exception is caught?

Tags: swift, debugging, error-handling

I'm working with a Swift model `Cardholder` which is initialized based on an API response, and I'm trying to figure out what happens if certain fields in the response are `null`. Here is a (simplified) `extension` of the `Cardholder` model with an initializer from a [`Decoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder):

```
extension Cardholder: DictionaryDeserializable, DictionarySerializable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case dateOfBirth = "date_of_birth"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        dateOfBirth = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .dateOfBirth)
    }
}
```

For the API response that I'm manually testing with, the `first_name` field is `null`, and what I'm finding is that the debugger steps straight to the end of the `init` method after the `firstName =` line:

[image: Xcode debugger with current line of execution at end of init]

This happens if I press the 'Step Over' or 'Step In' buttons.

From what I understand rom https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html, this `init` method is a throwing function which propagates errors that are thrown inside of it to the scope from which it’s called. How would I get to that scope to figure out what the ultimate consequences are of this error?

Comment: You can catch your error in a do, try, catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing an error in Swift is not an exception. It's just a fancy kind of return. You can step up the calling stack just like you would for return. Step-out; it's the button to the right of step-into.